# Slow Wifi after Suspend

Tags: wireless, 19.10

I'm using ubuntu 19.10 on a Thinkpad T430 and connecting to internet using wifi. Using speedtest-cli I get approximately 75 Mbit/s download speed and 20 Mbit/s upload speed. But once I close the computer lid and come back to it later, I consistently get about 3.5 Mbit/s. If I restart the computer the wifi goes back to normal (~75Mbit/s). I've tried restarting network manager but it has no effect.
Can someone help me with ways of troubleshooting this problem? Thanks in advance!

Output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; iwconfig`

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) [8086:1502] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Lenovo 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) [17aa:21f3]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
--
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] [8086:0085] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 (802.11a/b/g/n) [8086:1311]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
wlp3s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"TELUS1879-5G"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.24 GHz  Access Point: 70:F1:96:9F:6C:26   
          Bit Rate=270 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=63/70  Signal level=-47 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:5  Invalid misc:1410   Missed beacon:0

enp0s25   no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Update: January 10, 2020: This issue seemed to be resolved but then began intermittently again. I believe the source was the package windscribe-cli. I have removed the package and the wifi connection seems to be working fine again.

Comment: What wifi card?  Please edit question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; iwconfig`

Comment: I have updated the question with the output

Comment: `sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf && systemctl restart network-manager.service`  Does that help?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but the wifi has been working flawlessly for the last couple of days. I will keep tracking it and update if anything changes.